# listview with custom adapter not working correctly on scrolling

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I'm using a customAdapter to show mydata in a listview.
It has some condition which checks some fileds and then changes background color of linearlayout, or changes the color of some textview.

Every thing is right untill loading...problems are below:
1-After it when I scroll the list down and scroll back up color of the all items will change!!!
2- when i check one check box and scroll down some other rows will be check automatically!!!

3- I use this custom adapter in main activity.it's ok. but when i set listview.setOnItemClickListener for listview is won't work!!!

What is wrong with my code?

below is customadapter class codes:

```
package ir.telad.houseagancy;
... 
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList data;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
int i=0;
/*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d,String re) {
       /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(data.size()<=0)
        return 1;
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    public TextView name;
    public TextView moaref;
    public TextView address;
    public TextView tel;
    public TextView rahn;
    public TextView ejare;
    public TextView date;
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView foori;
    public LinearLayout layout1;
    public CheckBox checkBox;
    //public TableRow tblr;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View vi;
     final ViewHolder holder;
      ListModel tempValues;
     if(convertView==null){

         /****** Inflate list_item.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
         /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/
         holder = new ViewHolder();
         holder.layout1=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
         holder.checkBox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
         holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_txtName);
         holder.tel=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_txtTel);
         holder.address=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_txtAddress);
         holder.rahn=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_txtRahn);
         holder.ejare=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_txtEjare);
         holder.image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
         holder.foori=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_txtFoori);
         holder.date=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_txtDate);
         vi=convertView;
        /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
         convertView.setTag(holder);

     }
     else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         vi=convertView;
     }


     if(data.size()<=0)
     {
         holder.name.setText("no data");
         holder.address.setText("");

     }
     else
     {
         /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
         tempValues = ( ListModel ) data.get( position );
         /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
          holder.name.setText( tempValues.Name );
          holder.tel.setText( tempValues.Phone );
          holder.address.setText( tempValues.Address );
          holder.rahn.setText( tempValues.Rahn );
          holder.ejare.setText( tempValues.Ejare );
          holder.date.setText(tempValues.Date);

         holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                 if(b==true)
                     holder.layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(150,250,100,100));
                 else if(b==false) holder.layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
             }
         });
          if(tempValues.foori==1)
              holder.foori.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


          if(tempValues.state==3){
              //holder.tblr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
              holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3C7700"));
              holder.tel.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2C6700"));
              holder.rahn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#397249"));
              holder.ejare.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#92CD00"));
          }

          if(tempValues.isAzad==1){
              //holder.tblr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
              holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
              holder.tel.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
              holder.rahn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
              holder.ejare.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
          } 

     }
     return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

2-

Comment: I think Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
} should be Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

Comment: no it doesn't differs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have implemented only `if` case why not implemented `else` case
>   its happened because view is created every time when you scroll up and
>   down so define else also for check and color and to maintain the
>   `checkbox` checked or not you have to make a `int Array` in `adapter`
>   to save his checked state at specific position and put the `if else`
>   condition to check uncheck your checkbox.
>
> your `OnItemClick` is not working  because you are using `checkbox` in
>   `ListView` Custom Row, so there is on solution set `focusable` `false`
>   in `xml` of custom row and `true` in `listview` xml.
>
> hope it will help you.

Comment: else part worked :) but OnItemClick is not working yet! about checkbox you mean make an int array in custom adapter and when user checked the checkbox i set 1 to its postion in array? may u give some code snippets?

Comment: int[] checkPos = new int[data.size()];
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b==true) {
                    holder.layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(150, 250, 100, 100));
                    checkPos[position] = 1;
                } else if(b==false) {
                    holder.layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    checkPos[position] = 0;
                }
         }
});

Comment: if(checkPos[position]==1){
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

Comment: define int[] checkPos in global level and update your getView method by above code.

Comment: if OnItemClick still not working after define focusable then share your xml file too.

Comment: if(checkPos[position]==1){ holder.checkBox.setChecked(true); } else{ holder.checkBox.setChecked(false); }
             holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                     if(b==true) {
                         checkPos[position]=1;
                     }
                     else if(b==false) {

                         checkPos[position]=0;

Comment: above code is working better than before. but still when scrolling it's checked state will be unchecked  !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145383/discussion-between-s-hoseinpoor-and-aniruddh-parihar).